# Kendo UI Plotband to draw horizontal lines

Tags: plot, kendo-ui, linechart

I'm trying to create a chart with 2 horizontal lines using kendo, in order to draw those 2 lines, I'm using plotBands in the valueAxes.
I wish to draw the lines at the values warningMax and warningMin, the problem is that the values of them could be 3k or 350k, is there a way to adjust the thickness of the lines and place a min value in the axis to make sure that when values of series are too small, at least the red line would show at the top?

```
$("#DivId").kendoChart({
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            title: {
                text: "Title Name",
                font: "bold 24px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                color: "black"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line",
                style: "smooth",
                labels: {
                    visible: false,
                    format: "{0:c}"
                },
            },
            series: data.series,
            valueAxes: [{
                name: "axesName1",
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        from: warningMax,
                        to: warningMax + 50,
                        color: "green"
                    },
                    {
                         from: WarningMin,
                         to: WarningMin + 50,
                         color: "red"
                    }
                ],
                title: { text: "Axes Name1" },
                labels: {
                    format: "n0"
                },
                color: "#428bca" // Dark Blue
            }, {
                name: "axesName2",
                title: { text: "Axes Name2" },
                labels: {
                    format: "p2"
                },
                color: "#5cb85c" // Green
            }],
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: data.categories,
                axisCrossingValues: [0, 31],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try, instead of just adding 50, adding a value that is proportional to either the maximum value of your series or a percentage of `warningMax/warningMin`. Example: `to: WarningMin * 1.10`

Comment: That solves the problem of the thickness.
But when the values are too small, the lines don't show up because their values are not in the ValueAxes, how can I make the red line show at the top in this case?

Comment: To render a "plotband" of specific thickness, use this method: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/appearance/custom-plot-bands  To make sure the lines are visible you need to set the max and min properties of the valueAxis

Comment: @kadzu then you need to compute also the maximum / minimum value instead of having it automatically calculated by Kendo. That will bring another (possible) problem where the graph looks flat compared with the max/min values on the axis.